# Nodejs best practice encapsulating send middleware

Tags: node.js, middleware

Ok so I am currently learning more node.js and decided to try out some basic middleware in a small api I created. I was wondering how I would wrap a successfull request. This is my approach.

**Example Controller**

```
exports.getTask = async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const task = await db.Task.findOne(
            {
                where: {
                    id: req.params.taskId,
                    userId: req.params.userId
                }
            });
        if (task) {
            req.locals.data = task;
            res.status(httpStatus.OK);
            next();
        }
        res.status(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
```

**Middleware**

```
exports.success = function(req, res, next) {
    const success = res.statusCode < 400;
    const successResponse = {
        timestamp: new Date().toUTCString(),
        success: success,
        status: res.statusCode
    };

    if (success) {
        successResponse.data = req.locals.data;
    }
    res.send(successResponse);
    next();
};
```

I dont think its very good having to set `req.locals.data` for every requst and then calling next `res.status(status)` maybe I just approached the situation the wrong way?

How could you make this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, probably using the express middleware concept (calling `next()`) will be an overkill.

I'd approach this by creating an abstraction for the success path. Consider something like this:

```
const resWithSuccess = (req, res, data) => {
    res.json({
      data: data,
      timestamp: new Date().toUTCString(),
      // success: res.statusCode < 400, // --> actually you don't need this,
      //                                       since it will always be true
      // status: res.statusCode // --> or whatever else "meta" info you need
    });
};
```

Then, as soon as you need to respond with success, go for it:

```
exports.getTask = async function (req, res, next) {
    // .... bla bla
    if (task) {
        resWithSuccess(tank);
    }
};
```

PS: ... and you can use the express middleware concept (calling `next()`) for the error path.

Comment: Thanks! This was actually my first approach. I thought it would be a little bit too dramatic to wrap the response in every single controller but this is alot cleaner than using middleware. However I dont understand the PS. you mean calling next with an error like next(error) to invoke the error handler? This is something I am already doing.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your error path, with calling `next(error)`, looks all right.